# Scala example from a book related to trait

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to run above example. But it failed. Can someone help. I think i am missing something very basic.

```
 sealed trait List[+A]

    case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
    case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

    object List {
    def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
    case Nil => 0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs)
    }

    def product(ds: List[Double]): Double = ds match {
    case Nil => 1.0
    case Cons(0.0, _) => 0.0
    case Cons(x,xs) => x * product(xs)
    }

    def apply[A](as: A*): List[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
    }

ERROR

*scala> val x = (1 to 10).toList
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)*

*scala> List.sum(x)
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
 required: List(in object $iw)[Int]
       List.sum(x)*
                ^
```

Its an example from book. I tried by make List[Int] but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (and the compiler) are getting confused between the `List` object that you've defined, and the `List` provided by the standard library.  An easy mistake to make when they both have the same name.

The `toList` method of the `Range` object (1 to 10) returns a library `List` but your code wants to handle its own `List` type, not the library's.

You can create the proper type of List (i.e. your List) like this:

```
val x: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `List` by using the `Cons` and `Nil` case classes that you defined.

```
scala> Cons(0, Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil)))
res4: Cons[Int] = Cons(0,Cons(1,Cons(2,Nil)))

scala> List.sum(res4)
res5: Int = 3
```